# Australian student visa refusal

Tags: visa

I am from India. My student visa to Australia was refused 17 years ago, since then I haven't applied to any country. The letter I received from Australia High Commission is not specific and says "you do not meet the requirements set in Para C of attachment A.

Para C states the reason can be either of the following:

1. education background
2. employment history
3. level of English
4. relevance of proposed study/ employment
5. inconsistency of info with previous application
6. intention to comply with visa condition and leave Australia on completion.

Now I have got admission to New Zealand university and will be applying for student visa shortly, will it affect my visa processing? Should I attach the letter sent by Australian High Commission while applying for visa to New Zealand?

Answer (score 1):

Question D4 of the [New Zealand Student Visa Application (INZ 1012)](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/study/application/) asks:

> D4. Have you ever been refused a visa/permit to visit, work, study or reside in any country?

To this question you must answer Yes. (If you answer No, and they discover you lied, then you will have bigger problems.) Answering Yes will not automatically cause your application to be denied. The visa processing officer will take your entire case into consideration.

The section continues with:

> If you have answered yes to any of the questions above give full details. This includes full details of any charges,
>   convictions and the sentence or penalty imposed. Continue on a separate piece of paper if necessary.

This is where you would explain about your Australian visa refusal.